# Is the first stroke of "啟" 点 or 撇 or 横？

Tags: characters, strokes

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

The above images seem to indicate different answers.

Comment: The order of strokes are also different from each other, the first one is **丶乛一丿** while the second is **丿丿乛一**.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**Under which regional standard are you studying your characters? That'll be your answer.**

---

> Note: 橫 is a 隸書 style, and no region really writes it like that. You'll see Japanese people write 戶 with a 橫 instead, and that's where the influence comes from.

Comment: Interesting! How about mainland China standard before 1949? Comparing with the standards today, is it the same as PRC standard or ROC standard?

Comment: @Zuriel Interesting question, but I don't think there is an answer. This is because the "standard" in Mainland China was defined *after* 1949. Before, it was just whatever the people got taught, although mind you there were dictionaries and orthodox calligraphy guides around at that time (but I would not call them "official"). They were more similar to the ROC/HK standard (the PRC standard honestly is a bit far off from writing pre-1949, although that's mainly from Simplified Chinese rather than stroke differences).

Comment: Thank you! Also, I thought in mainland China only simplified Chinese is used. So they shouldn't have a standard for "啟" as they only use "启"？

Comment: @Zuriel Even "啟" wasn't standardized before. There are many variants of this character, one of the most common being: 啓. Standardization happened in the 1950s and 1960s to encourage literacy.

Comment: @Zuriel Mainland China has a standard set of Traditional Characters. They used that set to get their Simplified Chinese set in the first place, and keep on referring back to that set when they want to do more changes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_General_Standard_Chinese_Characters, specifically: *The list also offers an official table of correspondences between Simplified Chinese characters and Traditional Chinese characters (designating both 'standard' and selected 'variant' forms), **effectively serving as Mainland China's standardization scheme for Traditional Characters.***

Comment: Does traditional character form standardization in Mainland China serve any purpose outside of character simplification? I don't imagine anyone that needs to use traditional Chinese in Mainland China would follow it.

Comment: @wang_xiao_ming sorry, I don't know. I do know that it's generally unusable, since IMEs don't really support it. When the PRC publishes something in Traditional Chinese for public communication purposes, it usually uses the ROC (Taiwan) standard.

Answer (score 0):

To get it simple:
The first stroke of 啓 is 橫 only when you are writing calligraphy.
The first stroke of 啓 can be either 撇 or 點 when you write normally. They are basically the same. However , when you type 啓, the first stroke tends to be 撇.